# WordPress 404ing on static assets, but I can see the files at the URL being queried

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I built a theme on a local WordPress install. All worked beautifully. FTPed the theme directory  to the remote host. I can see all the files there. In WP-Admin, switched to my new theme, and not a single thing in the /themes/my_theme/assets/ directory is loading. No CSS, no JS, no images.

The file URL being queried is correct, according to the files I can see on the server:
`http://sitename.com/sub/wp-content/themes/my_theme/assets/css/site.css` is a valid path as far as I can tell, but is returning 404 on page load.

For the CSS, I am using styles.css to load in a bunch of files. I can access styles.css at `http://sitename.com/sub/wp-content/themes/my_theme/style.css`, but I can't access the file URL for any of the CSS it imports.

Both local & remote are running Wordpress 4.0.1.

I am using `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` to load the static in-template image assets. These are also outputting a full & correct path, but returning 404 on page load.

I am using `enqueue_scripts` in the functions.php file to load the JS. Again: outputting a full & correct path, but returning a 404 on page load.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

From my question: "What have I missed?"

Answer: The magic of FTP had totally borked the permissions on the /assets/ directory. Allowing read access fixed everything.

Comment: Similar thing happened after a .zip transfer -- permissions on a theme folder were off and inexplicable. Thanks for returning to your question

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem today. After an update of the plugin *WP Hide & Security Enhancer*.

Removed a line in the root *.htaccess*